# React : Handle multiple browser(s), browser tabs to restrict duplicate operations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser

I have a button `Submit` when clicked performs some operation calling an API. Post click, the button is disabled or basically the initial state of the button and the operation is changed.

I have two or multiple browser tabs which shows same screen of `Submit`. If in any one of the tab, the `Submit` operation is performed, the other tabs should show the updated version. The other tabs should show the disabled version and should not show the initial state.

How do I achieve this? I am using React, JS

[image]

Comment: With difficulty. What server-side framework are you using? You'd need to use some bi-directional system like SignalR or Pusher. If you're using a stateless server-side system like PHP then you're kinda SOL. Though you could use client-side `postMessage` but that won't work if the user is using different browsers or different machines.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting to do this on the clientside as a UX enhancement to go alongside a serverside restriction? Or are you looking for how to do the serverside restriction?

Comment: I am majorly looking for client side solution. looking if i can use SSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 Data duplication MUST be restricted at the server side.

- I would recommend some cache like [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache). Node-cache will having scalability issues, so better to go with [redis](https://redis.io/). (The logic should be smt. like: If the form has submited with the `user_id`, or with `form_id`, you can create a cache for that, and if you proceed it, store it in the db, other case throws an error. On the other browser you must validate before the `submit` if the `unique_id` neither in the cache nor in the `db`. If exists, you can throws an error in the nr.2 browser.

#2 If you want to disable the button, you have to use [`websockets`](https://medium.com/@tfarguts/websockets-for-beginners-part-1-10796106e207)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a client-only solution, here is a great [article](https://medium.com/@daverivera90/sharing-state-between-browser-tabs-with-redux-68899eb88fb7) about sharing state between browser tabs. The limitation is that it won't work on different browsers/machines.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this from a UI/UX perspective is to use validation. If `User A` clicks submit, then `User B` clicks submit from a different browser or tab, an error should be displayed to `User B` indicating that "This action has already taken place".

That being said, what you are trying to achieve is possible.

One way is by using a WebSocket. A WebSocket is a persistent connection between the client and server, that allows bi-directional communication.

The page with the submit button in your React app would be a "subscriber" to some websocket channel. When the submit button is clicked for the first time(it doesn't matter from where), a message can be "published" from a WebSocket server to `ALL` subscribers, regardless of the browser or tab being used.

Basically, you would add an `onMessage` handler in your React app where you can disable the submit button when a specific message is received.

I don't know what tech you are using on the server side, but for a WebSocket server, there are many options out there. For the React app, there is [react-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-websocket) which is straight-forward to use.

Comment: "PubSub" is irrelevant here. Just simple message-forwarding over WebSockets is needed, not an entire Pub/Sub system. In fact you don't even need WebSockets either, you can use SSE for server-to-client and a normal `fetch` for client-to-server.

Comment: @Dai - Correct, a PubSub system is not really needed here. I was not aware of SSE. It would be great if you could post an answer with some more detail on that.

Comment: I _could_, but it's 4am here. I'll just link this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in client-side

```js
const Form = () => {
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisable] = useState(false);

  // first tab fire
  const onSubmit = () => {
    .
    .
    .
    localStorage.setItem("formSubmited", "true");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const disableButton = (e) => {
      if (e.storageArea.formSubmited) {
        setButtonDisable(true);
      }
    };
    // second tab fire
    window.addEventListener("storage", disableButton);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", disableButton);
    };
  }, []);
 .
 .
 .
};
```

Comment: How this will handle different browser button click events?

Comment: this handle only tabs on same browser.